E/I separation for GEO statellites
Two GEO satellites are being colocated using the E/I separation method. Typically, the eccentricity vector would trace a circular motion with the circle positioned in the first quadrant of the Ex-Ey coordinate system (from March to June). However, the plot I generated from two actual satellites shows them in two different quadrants (first and fourth quadrants) despite being at the same time in March.
I do not understand why this is happening. Could you please explain?





Very nice plot! I wish we could see it in 3D somehow. (older and different but related: How are co-located satellites positioned relative to each other?)

Assuming the two objects really are in an e-i separation, this answer addresses the part of the puzzle that you have shown, the eccentricity vector,  and makes wild guesses about the rest, but bear with me, it will help.
As you point out "Typically, the eccentricity vector would trace a circular motion":

this happens to any object under the influence of solar radiation pressure but it is clearer for objects with a large area/mass.
to see it in a plot like this also relies upon the other influences being comparatively small. In this case it looks like manoeuvres are dominating the eccentricity so you don't see circles, though if this is only 90 days of data then circles aren't out of the question for a whole year of data.

It is clear that by keeping eccentricity vectors of the two satellites in opposite quadrants that one's apogee will be positioned at the same hour angle as the perigee of the other.

that creates an in-plane separation at the apogee and perigee though not at the points halfway between these.
one way for the the owners to keep the two satellites safe is arrange that there is also always a small difference in inclination of these orbits, again managed through station-keeping,

most importantly: so that the nodal crossing of the orbit planes occurs at the respective  apogee/perigee points.



So if these two objects are in e-i separation then you also need to look at their inclination vector evolution and think about whether there is radial separation at the plane crossing at all times of year.
As a suggestion, just glancing at the ex/ey plot you have already posted, if you can plot the two satellite's eccentricity and inclination vectors a month at a time for a year (e.g. separate plots for each month) then it will probably be sufficient to demonstrate the separation condition, if not you might need finer detail through the year.
EDIT
Just remembered a similar answer I wrote a while back: How does the "eccentricity-inclination vector separation" technique work for colocated GEO satellites?

Thank you so much for your explanation. The plots of two satellites corresponded with the ex/ey I provided. The duration of the plots is 1.5 months (from the middle of March to the end of April).
As you said, they are maneuvered at the apogees and perigees instead of the Sun pointing perigee strategies.
